# Using Open CPU to expose R model as rest API

Tags: r, reactjs, opencpu

I have built some R models which has some 20 output metrics which I want to show in the frontend UI which is built using ReactJS. 
The application basically takes CSV files which user uploads and that is fed internally to the R models. My plan is to store the files that the user uploads in a cloud server .I am planning to use open CPU to expose my entire R program as a package and then make these uploaded files to connect to R models by making an internal call

https://server-name/ocpu/library/package/R/function -F "input=@test.csv"

Once the r models processing is complete , I will output the entire results as a as json and give it to the UI.

Please advice if this approach is feasible. I doing this for first time and unsure about this approach. 
Thanks!!

Comment: Yes that sounds like a plan.

Comment: @Jeroen: I am trying to expose a sample r model as API . In my local machine , I am able to get the output using the command :curl http://local host/5656/ocpu/library/mypackage/R/tv/json -F "input=@test.csv" but when I am trying the same in my linux cloud server , I am not getting the output. I tried the command :curl http://13.228.109.233:8787/p/5656/ocpu/library/mypackage/R/tv -F "input=@test.csv" and I get the output as http:&#x2F;&#x2F;13.228.109.233:8787&#x2F;auth-sign-in?appUri=%2Fp%2F5656%2Focpu%2Flibrary%2Fmypackage%2FR%2Ftv%2Fjson . I am not able to get what it means?